# How can I quickly see/test/check all colorscheme's available in Vim?

Tags: colorscheme, theme

I want to quickly see all colorscheme's available in Vim, without having to click many places or run a lot of manual commands. Is there an automated way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[image: animation showing testing different colorschemes]

```
for c in globpath(&rtp, 'colors/*.vim', 0, 1)->map({_, val -> fnamemodify(val, ':t:r')})->sort('i')->uniq('i')
  try
    exec 'colorscheme ' .. c
    redraw
    echo c
  catch
    echo 'ERROR loading colorscheme ' .. c
  finally
    sleep 2
  endtry
endfor
colorscheme default
redraw
echo 'finished. back to default'
```

Save the file and run it with `:so %`

(thanks @romainl and @Jürgen Krämer for the improvements suggestions!)

Comment: You are missing all the user's colorschemes with your script.

Comment: You don't need an external file. Replace the `for c in` loop with `for c in uniq(sort(map(globpath(&rtp, 'colors/*.vim', 0, 1), {key, val -> fnamemodify(val, ':t:r')}), 'i'), 'i')` and Vim will give you a list of all available colorschemes, including the ones from the user themself and from 3rd party packages.

Comment: Great, thanks! Successfully tested on Linux and Windows, GVim and terminal Vim. Updated the code. I changed the chained function calls to become methods.

Comment: I found a plugin to switch between colorschemes. Haven't tested it, though. https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-colorscheme-switcher

Comment: I don't know why, it's very slow on Linux GVim. Tried replacing `redraw` with `redraw!`, but it didn't work.